# SMTP Error(220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am current using CodeIgniter 2.2.2 and I have the following code inside my controller:

```
        $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
        $config['smtp_host'] = "mail.domain.com";
        $config['smtp_port'] = "25";
        $config['smtp_user'] = "noreply@somedomain.com"; 
        $config['smtp_pass'] = "password";
        $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
        $config['mailtype'] = "html";
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->initialize($config);

        $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
        $this->email->from('noreply@somedomain.com', 'www.somedomain.com');
        $this->email->to('someEmail');


        $this->email->subject('Email Authentication');
        $message = 'Hi';

        $this->email->message($message);

        $this->email->send();
```

I tried using port 465, and ssl://xxxxxxx.prod.iad2.secureserver.net. But i am getting no luck at all. I tried contacting the customer service, but nope. They really didn't help me much other than giving me links into things I already knew.
Why am I getting the message? It is preventing me to send email to my other email addresses.
Can anyone please help here?

Comment: When you say "but nope" what was the result of contacting them?

Comment: They told me to try another server basically. They said they don't support this kind of operations. I tried to be cleared and provided my setting and codes, Then they give me the guide about creating a email address (which I already did.)

Comment: could you solve this?

Comment: I had the same problem and error message. I contacted the hosting provider and they determined that the email account I use to send emails has been automatically blocked due to "malicious activities". So they unblocked the email account and advised me to change its password. That solved the issue on my end.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm having the same problem. After some research I found that the solution for me was:

```
 $config['protocol'] = "mail";
 $config['smtp_port'] = 587;
```

Comment: works like a charm :)

Comment: Wow! Glad I found this page! Who woulda thunk? I called GoDaddy for support on this issue, and the tech talked down to me like I was a lost little boy at Disneyland.

Comment: this should be the selected answer, thanks a lot i waist 4 hours for this issue.

Comment: For me, this change make CodeIgniter not throw error anymore, but the mail is not sent anyway.

Comment: Beware, sometimes email will not be received to recipient. Use SMTP to have a good success rate of delivery.

Comment: it is works men thanks to you

Comment: it is working  bro thank you

Comment: I don't get it, where do I have to put or edit that?